# Marionette Events, async callback from child to parent event?

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous, marionette

I have an index view that calls a collection and therefore item view. The user can tick items and then click copy in index template.

The code below works fine, the item has a event triggered in the index. However, the problem is, I want to be able to know when all the events have finished copying those posts. The only way I can think of doing it is moving the copy logic into the index view but I do consider this an item view action.

posts/index.js

```
// copy posts from the collection
        onClickCopyPosts: function() {
            // are we sure we want to delete these posts
            var platform = $('#copyPlatforms option:selected').val();
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to copy these posts to that platform?')) {
                // get the post ids of the ticked posts
                var postIds = this.getSelectedPostsArray();
                _.each (postIds, function (postId, key) {
                    MyApp.vent.trigger('post:copy:'+postId, platform);
                })
            }
        },
```

item.js

```
    initialize: function () {

        var that = this;

        this.listenTo(MyApp.vent, 'post:copy:'+this.model.get('id'), function(platform) {
            // fetch the collection and pass its filters through
            that.onCopy(platform);
        });
    },

       onCopy: function(platform) {

            // copy the current model to a new variable
            var modelJSON = this.model.toJSON();

            // set platform to the platform passed to the method
            modelJSON.platform = platform;

            modelJSON = Factory.create(modelJSON);

            // create a new instance of that model
            var newModel = new Model(modelJSON);

            // save the new model
            newModel.save({}, {
                success: function() {
                    //console.log('copy post', 'success');
                },
                error: function() {
                    //console.log('copy post', 'error');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    //console.log('copy post', 'complete');
                }
            });
            return;
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should redesign this to save a group of models rather than triggering an event for each save. This way you could listen to to a group of XHRS using Jquerys [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to fire a callback when everything is done.

See [Brian Mann's solution](https://github.com/brian-mann/sc02-loading-views/blob/master/sc02-loading-views-after/app/assets/javascripts/backbone/entities/_base/_utilities.js.coffee) he allows any number of syncable backbone entities to fire a `"when:fetched"` event but the same could be utilised for saving your models. Good [Video](http://www.backbonerails.com/screencasts/loading-views) on this.